# Notepad++ changing written format of text

Tags: notepad++, programmers-notepad

Hey guys I have a bunch of information on one notepad but its all jumbled up and I was hoping you guys could help me put it together and make it in the form of:

```
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

Where a,b,c,d can be variables such as name,fav food,skin colour,hair colour.
OR something along those lines.

Right now these variables are in the form of:

```
a

b
<SP>
c
<SP>
d
<SP>

<SP>
a (and this is where it starts again in the same format)
```

The `<SP>`'s stand for a space, i didn't know how else to annotate them it just comes up as a empty line with a space...

Is there any way of converting this into the other format?

Comment: So before the first `a` there is no `<SP>` ? And between the first `a` and `b` there is also no `<SP>` ?

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ go to Replace, and set it to Extended mode.

- First replace `\n \n` (there is a whitespace in the middle!) with `,` to replace all lines with just a space into commas on the same line.
- Then replace `\n\n` with `\n` to remove the empty lines that are left.
- And replace `\n,' with`\n` to remove all leading commas.
- Lastly replace `,\n` with `\n` to remove all trailing commas

Comment: sorry that first bit didnt work at the bottom it says Replace All:0

Comment: @user3689025 well, I was assuming you had mistakes in your OP, but you replied 'yes exactly that'. So tell me, what is it that makes you know when to start a new line ?

Comment: sorry could you please rephrase that? but the example ive shown is exactly how the format is... do you want me to upload the file to show you how the format is? please just show me where to upload it

Comment: @user3689025 well, if between the first `a` and `b` there is no `<SP>`, then how do you know `a` and `b` belong on the same line?

Comment: they dont belong on the same line? its a new paragraph.

Comment: @user3689025 but you say you want to end up with `a,b,c,d`. So how do you know `a` and `b` should be on the same line?

Comment: http://up.ht/1ozv3km

If you open that in Notepad++ you might understand what I'm trying to explain. Sorry if the way I explained it before didn't make sense.

Comment: @user3689025 i assume that file is the way you want it to be. Im more interested in how the file is when you start.

Comment: no thats the way the file is currently? The way i want it to be is all of one persons information on one line spaced out by comma's, and then all of another persons information on a separate line with their information spaced out by commas too..

Comment: hi sorry any new help :/ ? i really need this very soon :/

Please help me or else im going to have to do this manually!!